Upgraded from 22.04 to 24.04 and Python is broken with 3.12.7-1+jammy1
Upgraded Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 and have a few Python projects to install, including Home Assistant, there are some requirements and I have not been able to resolve how to get them installed... the Python headers are missing. I get this unmet dependencies. I have tried a lot of different things to fix it, but I'm not sure how to get around this.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.12-dev : Depends: python3.12 (= 3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) but 3.12.7-1+jammy1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libpython3.12-dev (= 3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libpython3.12t64 (= 3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


Did you manually change the python version?

These dependent packages are available in deepsnake repositary. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa Then update the packages list. sudo apt update Now install the required package; these dependencies will be resolved.

This does not answer the question. These packages are supposed to be available in the default repositories. Python is an important system component. Replacing default python packages with an external repository can be disastrous.

@ArchismanPanigrahi I don't think I manually changed the python version, I do use multiple versions of python though...
It appears to be still in automatic mode where I left it.
`
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).
Selection    Path                 Priority   Status

0            /usr/bin/python3.8    3         auto mode
1            /usr/bin/python3.12   1         manual mode
2            /usr/bin/python3.8    3         manual mode
`


What is the output of sudo apt update ? It seems that your ubuntu is still trying to install 22.04 python in 24.04
